# How to give different labels for the two textboxes in Struts doubleselect tag?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

The struts provides a tag `<s:doubleselect>` for rendering two interdependent textbox. But to give labels for both boxes there is only one key attribute. It gives a common label for both boxes. I need to give two different labels. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Set the strus2 theme to simple (best to set in struts.xml so it's global) then just use html and jQuery to do what you need. Anywhere ajax or some kind of client side functionality is needed that is the best way. For basic form handling, iteration, etc the struts2 tags are very useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:doubleselect name="" list="" listKey="" listValue="" doubleList="" doubleName="" doubleListKey="" doubleListValue=""/>
```

name & doubleName can be used to give different names to both textboxes.

Comment: name and doubleName can be used give names to retrieve them in action file.. but I'm asking how to **label** them both..:).. A label that appears befor the textbox...

Comment: @Laks: You literally said "name" instead of "label" throughout the question. I've edited the question.

Comment: there's no straight way to do that, in that case you can try using sj:select. Nice example here http://www.onlinexamples.com/showfullexample.action?idexamples=48&title=Dependent%20Select%20-%20Dependent%20Dropdowns%20-%20Triple%20Select%20Using%20Jquery